# Java Apache Http Client - Underscores in Headers only via HTTPS are dropped

Tags: java, http, https

I'm trying to use the default Apache HttpClient for a Post Request with Headers containing underscores to authorize against a legacy system.

When using HTTP the headers are beingsend. 
But when using HTTPS the headers with underscores are dropped silently.

I also tried using the native java http client. With this one it works like a charm.

Any chance getting it to work with apache?

**Apache Version** (org.apache.httpcomponents.httpclient.4.5.9)

```
CloseableHttpClient httpclient = HttpClients.createDefault();

HttpPost httppost = new HttpPost(
        "https://someHttpsResource");
    httppost.addHeader("header_with_underscore", "someValue");

CloseableHttpResponse response = httpclient.execute(httppost)
```

Cheers

Comment: Are you sure it's because of the Apache HTTP Client library? Maybe the endpoint you are calling has some load balancing policy that drops the headers with underscore only on HTTPS. Just an idea. Could you try the same request on a different endpoint?

Comment: Yes it is the HTTP Library. 
I Also tried the same scenario with SOAPUi which also uses the apache library under the hood.